Switching ON/OFF an ADC line
which electronic component could one use to switch ON/OFF several external lines for ADC?
Context:
I am working on a small project where I would like to measure 4 external voltages (0-3V range, let's call them VINs) with an NRF52 development board (ADC inputs). I am aiming for a low-power (or as low as possible) device that would measure for a short time once a minute.
I want to use 3 main components: MCU, LDO, and TIMER.

LDO (MCP1711) regulates the VCC = 3V;
MCU (NRF52) reads the 4 VINs and then tells the TIMER it has finished.
TIMER (TPL5111) sends a POWER OFF signal to the LDO, shutting off everything (VCC = 0V) for about a minute.

However, I have a problem with the implementation - VINs stay present and are much higher than what MCU's ADC can tolerate when VCC is 0V - Probably resulting in some sort of destruction in a long-run.
So, I would like to add a "switch" to each ADC input, that would close (connecting VINs to ADC) when LDO gives 3V and open when 0V (disconnecting ADC and VINs).
Current research results:

MOSFETs (or similar) - add one to each ADC channel that would act as the desired switch. However, I would rather have a single component for this - is there something like a Transistor Array with 4 switches inside? Also, can they be controlled (close/open) with only 3V VCC from the LDO?
Analog Switches - this is still an "unknown" for me, but is there a "4 input -> 4 output" analog switch that might fit the use case? I found that they more often "route" an input to several potential outputs.
Any better alternatives? - I do not even know what exists out there. Perhaps there are some obvious solutions that I have missed.

Additionally:

If any voltage drop occurs in these switches distorting the VIN, I could correct it with software - but would rather not do so.
There is no special requirement on switching speed, frequencies, or any of that sort, just reading the VIN value once a minute.
Compactness would be a huge benefit.


Well, there's a couple possibilities:

Don't care.  If the input currents are small enough, there's no wear on the ESD clamp diodes*, and VCC lifts imperceptibly against the normal loads on it (MCU and etc. I suppose).
This seems a bit far-out, as a low-power circuit can easily be parasite-powered from a few µA, and might operate completely normally for one (aside from the input error due to clamping current), or at reduced voltage (a device might run at 3.3v nominally but continue working down to 1.8V or less, without reduction in clock speeds), or intermittently (starts up, current draw spikes, browns itself out), for another.  Such operation might bring other hazards, like the CPU halting/crashing from faulty logic decisions in a brownout condition (setting the brown-out detect and watchdog would be prudent steps).
It also seems unlikely, in that, if the input dividers feed the ADC directly, they generally need to be a lowish impedance (10k?) to minimize sampling error.  Large-value dividers can still be read accurately with an op-amp voltage follower, but you may want to minimize component count as well.
*Assumption. Some devices uses zeners or snapback diodes instead, which might not be rated for any DC current injection. Check the datasheet.

Disconnect the inputs.  Analog switches are probably N/A as they require supplies to bias the transistors within.  A CMOS version of suitable ratings might be available, that can be always-powered: for example, DG403 claims typical 10nA on all supplies when not switching.

Use a discrete circuit.  If the input voltage is low (say, 0-1 or 0-2V range), a single MOSFET can be used to disconnect it:



simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Ironically, this might not be guaranteed better leakage than a switch proper (in fact the other way around), but only in that jellybean transistors aren't rated anywhere near their actual leakage currents, simply because it costs testing time to resolve such small currents.  ~pA gate leakage is typical; datasheets normally publish 1µA or so for expedience.  CMOS logic gate families as well, they're usually much better than datasheet limits for the same reason.  And you can find low-leakage types, for when you need the design guarantee.
Note that this method fails when the input voltage exceeds a bit below VDD - Vgs(th): in this range, Rds(on) rises asymptotically towards infinity.  It's fine (Rds(on) low and stable) while voltage remains low.  Gate voltage can also be obtained from a boost supply (say, toggle a pin into a half-wave voltage doubler, and "stack" that on top of VDD to drive G), to extend linear range above the supply.
Depending on ADC characteristics, this may be acceptable.  For example, a 10 or 12-bit ADC might be effective at 1 or 2V VREF, without increased INL/DNL/offset/noise/etc.

Use the MCU's own sleep features; keep it powered on.
I don't know the capabilities offhand, but NRF52 family devices are used in a lot of things, so they must not be too bad.  This will generally be the more complex and limited method (well, depends what else's connected to the MCU -- make sure it's not parasite-powered, not sending any erroneous logic levels when disconnected, etc...), but it will be limited by what the MCU offers (actual leakage in X sleep mode(s)), and what peripherals are needed vs. available in what sleep states.  But I would also say, it is worth exploring regardless, to get comfortable with low-power design and programming.


Note that you likely need ESD clamping and filtering on these signals, which is its own separate question/issue.  I gather the signals are low bandwidth at least, so that pretty generous filtering might suffice for both EMI and ESD.


which electronic component could one use to switch ON/OFF several
external lines for ADC?

Analog switches and multiplexers come to mind, most designs have two parallel mosfets, one pmos and one nmos to be able to 'send through' any analog current with minimal resistance.

Any better alternatives? - I do not even know what exists out there.
Perhaps there are some obvious solutions that I have missed.

You could use multiple opamps with an enable (or shutdown) line also which would be a switchable impedance buffer.

But switches/muxes require external power. Do you know of any that can be powered down?

Not that I know of, the ones I've used are not high-Z. You could probably find an opamp that might do that in shudown.
